# No puedo poner texto o operaciones en jaspersoft studio: wrong name

Tags: java, jaspersoft

He creado una plantilla en **jaspersoft** la cual se compila y desde java creo un **pdf** pasando la información, el problema es que hay una variable que no quiero mostrarla en la ultima pagina pero si pongo en

```
Print When Expresion $V{PAGE_NUMBER} != $V{PAGE_COUNT}
```

me salta el error:

```
Reporte (wrong name: Reporte_3dc3335aad3f4664cb285e02d0694faf477f6a7df179bb1ecdaadc1d44a10091)
```

ja que he escrito `!=` y no se como solucionarlo para que la variable no se muestre en la ultima pagina.

Comment: Ojo con `PAGE_COUNT`: la [documentación](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVariable.html#PAGE_COUNT) dice que _contiene el número de registros que han sido procesados cuando al ser generada la página actual_. ¿Realmente es esa la variable que estás queriendo usar?

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora tengo una variable que contiene el total de paginas, se llama "TotalPaginas", pero sigo sin poder resolver el error anterior.

Comment: Lo extraño es el error que te está dando. Realmente no recuerdo mucho de Jasper; ¿probaste parseando los valores de las variables a Integer? ¿En dónde estás haciendo el _Print When Expression_?

Comment: Si, el problema es que si escribo algo de texto entre comillas o los símbolos de las operaciones salta ese error, y no se que hacer.

Comment: ¿Ese _wrong name_ es un _NoClassDefFoundError_? ¿Aparece ese mismo mensaje de error cuando eliminás la comparación que mencionás que da error?

Comment: Siempre nos ayuda ver el jrxml, por lo menos la parte del elemento en cuestión. Verifica que la *Evaluation Time* del campo sea `Page` o `Now`.